# jquery- close jquery Ui dialog with buttons with special attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

i have a button as below that is inside of my dialog div

```
<button id="BtnCancel" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"> </button>
```

now i want to close dialog when the button is clicked

in fact i have many dialog in my project that have buttons like above and i want to close every dialog when its inner button is clicked

how can i do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add code in the description for what you have tried so far and more description about issue you are facing.

Comment: @tejashsoni111 please see the question again